# React Native FlatList, change numColumns dynamically according to array value

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i want to add line break after "Patients", "Sales Revenue" etc .i.e after a label.
if i can change numcolumns to 1 if json array value=="label".

basically i want to use them as label with some margin up and down and 100% width.

please see images attached to be clear

[expo front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr54H.png)
[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ke7m.png)

Comment: FlatList does"t support dynamically changing column numbers at run-time. Try to do that will throw error or crash app in production

Comment: ok, thank you. I solved it by using flatlist for each section.